# ActiveX COM not releasing all objects

Tags: c#, com, activex, unmarshalling

I have a problem that may be too specific for me to get any help here, but I thought i would try. I've created an ActiveX connection with a COM object which is placed in my UI. The wrapper implements AxHost. The problem I am having is that when I close my View where the COM object resides, and then try to reopen it, I am not able to log in.

I am new to both ActiveX and COM, but I have figured out that I am not closing all objects properly. I've read up on and tried several solutions to this, but none of them seem to work. Currently, I have overridden the wrapper Dispose method to try to destroy the connection as follows:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ocx);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

As far as I can tell, ocx is the only COM object created. In the view class, I also try to get rid of all reference to the COM object like so:

```
protected void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                wrapper.CloseCanvasPage(canvasPageId, false);
                IsLoggedIn = !wrapper.Logout();
                wrapper.EndInit();
                wrapper.Dispose();
                wrapper = null;

                //  Garbage collect the unclosed ActiveX connections.
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
```

I realize that manually calling garbage collection is bad, but several posts said this would get rid of stray connections. It doesn't seem to work.

In the parent, I call Dispose on the view, and set it to null, trying to break any connections, but I still have something hanging around. When I try to create a new connection, and call Initialized (a property included in the wrapper I am using), I get notification that the COM object is already initialized. However, if I try to log in, I get an error code stating that it is not initialized.

Does anyone have ideas on any obvious (or not so obvious) mistakes I may have made? I would be happy to provide more information if it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're garbage-collecting the object correctly as far as I can see. The only thing I can suggest is to use C++/CLI for the wrapper. This way you wouldn't be using an RCW (Runtime Callable Wrapper) for the COM object, but the COM object directly. You would call IUnknown::Release directly. But I'm not sure it's a good idea to call IUnknown::Release multiple times until the reference count is 0 (like FinalReleaseComObject). If you have to do that, it means that some code is forgetting to Release the object (a memory leak), and using FinalReleaseComObject is a poor way to solve the problem.

It's also possible that there's just something wrong in your Initialized property, but I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using the wrapper the other company provided me with, but I have considered rewriting it so I could make sure all connections were closed. Again, I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (from a while ago though), you'll have to call GC.collect() TWICE, if you really want to get rid of ALL lingering objects.